# Running Taipy Rest on a specific port

Tags: python, python-3.x, taipy

I'm doing the [Taipy Core Getting Started](https://github.com/Avaiga/taipy-getting-started-core/blob/develop/src/step_09.py). I want to change the default port of the Rest endpoint, but I couldn't find the option in the documentation.

Here's a code snippet:

```
from taipy.core.config import Config, Frequency
import taipy as tp
import datetime as dt
import time

# code

if __name__=="__main__":
    tp.Core().run()
    scenario_1 = tp.create_scenario(scenario_cfg)
    scenario_1.subscribe(callback_scenario_state)

    scenario_1.submit(wait=True)
    
    tp.Rest().run()
```